# Line closest to a set of points

Tags: c++, algorithm, geometry

Given a set of `points` `S (x, y)`.

Find the `line` whose distance from all the points is minimum ?
That is, minimize the sum of distances (in absolute value or squared) between each point and the optimal line.

By distance I mean the shortest distance between the point and the line.
That is, the most common one, the euclidean distance in euclidean space.

I tried googling but could not find any relevant results, is there any line sweep algorithm that can do the task?

Comment: Are there any restrictions to the problem?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas we can assume x,y < N N is any integer.

Comment: Do you mean something significantly different from a linear regression?

Comment: @JerryCoffin preferably yes

Comment: @Ninja420: that was more or less an invitation to tell us *how* it would differ. As in: what you've described so far sounds pretty much like linear regression. If that's not what you want, then you probably need to give more description.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Maybe they mean [Deming regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deming_regression)?

Comment: @jdphenix: Could be -- without more information we're pretty much just taking wild guesses.

Comment: @JerryCoffin i misunderstood linear regression, i read about it, somewhat the problem is similar.

Comment: There's no such thing as "distance from all the points". There are many points and many distances. You may want to minimize the *sum* of all distances, or (as is often done) the sum of all *squared* distances, or perhaps some other function of all distances.

Comment: @Ninja420 that the problem is "similar" to linear regression doesn't help us much. How is it "different" ? Is this a textbook/homework problem? If so, what is the exact question? If it has arisen in the context of a bigger problem, what is that bigger problem? There are many algorithms to solve lots of problems which are similar to linear regression, but unless you describe your problem better (so we know what you want) you probably won't get a helpful answer.

Comment: I disagree with the assertion that this question is a duplicate. As @n.m. pointed out, there is no statement in the question regarding which function of the distances between the line and the points needs to be minimized. Linear regression minimizes the sum of squared distances; there is no reason to believe that the question is about that. As I read it, the question was about minimizing maximal distance between the line and the set of points. In such case the best answer would be to find the minimal diameter of the set and place line through the middle of the diameter orthogonally to it.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are trying to fit a curve/line, thus I would suggest least squares fitting for your case.

You can have a look at: http://www.alglib.net/interpolation/leastsquares.php

Hope it helps. :-)

Comment: Least squares, a.k.a. linear regression, is the most popular line fitting technique indeed, but it is not the universal solution to all line fitting problems. Sometimes one needs to minimize maximal distance, not sum of squared distances, and the answer in such case would be quite different.